# Server-side python script with long execution time in the context of a website

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, web, artificial-intelligence

I have website project that requires this :

The user can prompt the website to launch a python script (basically a trained AI that will operate on some data given by the user).

*Unfortunately, the execution time of such a script is a bit long, (approximately 1min30) because it involves scrapping web pages, analyzing them, it's a slow process.*

I am not well informed in this specific field and here are my questions :

- What happens if a lot of different users prompt at the same time ? What sort of solution would you use in order to avoid this ? Do I need to program a task manager or something like this ?
- Is this dangerous ?
- Is translating the AI into js and running the script client-side possible ?

Thanks in advance for your input.
This is my first post, I'm sorry if this doesn't belong here.

Comment: that's a good first question.

You might want to look into:
1. Asynchronous request processing to handle requests with long response times. The request might return an execution ID and the client will be polling on the execution ID to check result.
2. For the use case to address a lot of concurrent requests, it would be better to handle to start with a queuing mechanism with parallel processing at the Python layer and write execution results to an in-memory cache or a distributed database.

Comment: Thanks, I finally went for a simple message queue architecture. The node server sends a task to the MQ handler, and a node consumer executes the tasks one at the time (because there is no need to do parallel processing in my context), then mark the task as done. For the persons that need the information : the amqplib node package paired with a rabbitMQ instance does the job.